# Multicolored Tab Bar in Flutter. One color for each tab

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar, appbar

My doubt is similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66626714/flutter-tab-background-color-in-tabbar-multicolor-tabbar). I need a multicolor tabbar. Also, each tab should be empty, being represented just by the backgroundcolor.

Trying to achieve:

[image]

For now, I have this:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class LinhaPage extends StatefulWidget {
const LinhaPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_LinhaPageState createState() => _LinhaPageState();
}

class _LinhaPageState extends State<LinhaPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 1,
        length: 9,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Linha 1',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36.0),
            ),
            toolbarHeight: 80.0,
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFFAECA0A),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFFE4003A),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFF09BBEF),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFF154194),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFF50842C),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFFC7077F),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFFF49200),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFFF2E500),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: BtnAppBar(corBotao: 0xFF000000),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

and:

```
class BtnAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final corBotao;
  const BtnAppBar({Key? key, required this.corBotao}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Container(
      color: Color(corBotao),
      child: Text("1"),
    ));
  }
}
```

TKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide size on tabBar container using `MediaQuery` or `LayoutBuilder`. And use zero padding on `labelPadding`

```dart
bottom: const TabBar(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  isScrollable: true,
  tabs: <Widget>[
```

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Color(corBotao),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 9,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text("1"),
  );
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [tabs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs)